# Typescript, HashMap using hashcode and equal function

Tags: typescript, hashmap

I'm writing a typescript browser game.

I need to store an int vector3 (map position) as the map key.

Since we can't store reference type into the key of typescript Object and Map. (I mean we could for Map but cannot lookup without holding the same reference)

And there are solutions are suggested on the internet such as nested maps or stringify keys.

I want to find a more elegant solution using hashcode and equals.

Is there any suggest solution or npm library?

Comment: Why is hashcode/equals more “elegant” than stringifying keys?  The former means you have to implement a multimap that stores all the keys with the same hashcode. If you can compute a unique key then you can just use a regular map.  For a vector of three integers you can just do a `join` to get such a key.

Comment: I don't want to stringify since this will need to manipulate many strings in each frame. The possible way I'm looking for is to compute the hash as you said. But the thing is since int vector3 use 3 integers there are certain possibility to have collisions to hash it into 1 an integer. Except I'm going to limit the range of each int in vector3.

Comment: @jcalz BTW, Thank for the suggestion.. The compute unique hash is also in my consideration.

Comment: Do you have some evidence that concatenating numbers into a string will be slower than resolving hash collisions with a multimap? It seems like premature optimization to assume that the easy solution will have unacceptable performance.

Comment: No I don't.. And that's a good point tho.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, End up following your suggestion, I'm using stringifying first. Will revisit to optimize if needed. However, will open this question for the people who looking for multi-map solution.

Comment: I'm also interested in the question, not that much because of performance concerns, but type checkings: I feel like stringifying keys breaks the interest of using typescript.
Didn't find much neither on the Internet: [npm hashmap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashmap) is not far from it, appart the remaining to-do: "Allow extending the hashing function in a AOP way or by passing a service" :(

Answer (score 1):

In as much as I could not answer the question easily for myself from what I had found on the Internet, I share a quick implementation, borrowed from Python experience (not fully tested).

The idea is to have the `Hashable.hash()` function return a `number` or a `string` that will let the `HashableMap` know when key objects are actually the same.

```js
export interface Hashable {
    hash(): InnerHashKey;
}

export class HashableMap<K extends Hashable, V> extends Map<K, V> {
    private readonly _innerMap: InnerMap<K, V> = new InnerMap<K, V>();

    // Map<K, V> interface overload.
    public get(key: K): V | undefined {
        return this._innerMap.get(key.hash())?.value;
    }
    public has(key: K): boolean {
        return this._innerMap.has(key.hash());
    }
    public set(key: K, value: V): this {
        this._innerMap.set(key.hash(), {key: key, value: value});
        return this;
    }
    public delete(key: K): boolean {
        return this._innerMap.delete(key.hash());
    }
    public get size(): number {
        return this._innerMap.size;
    }
    public forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void {
        this._innerMap.forEach((value: InnerValue<K, V>): void => callbackfn(value.value, value.key, thisArg));
    }
    public entries(): IterableIterator<[K, V]> {
        return Array.from(this._innerMap.values()).map((value: InnerValue<K, V>): [K, V] => [value.key, value.value]).values();
    }
    public keys(): IterableIterator<K> {
        return Array.from(this._innerMap.values()).map((value: InnerValue<K, V>): K => value.key).values();
    }
    public values(): IterableIterator<V> {
        return Array.from(this._innerMap.values()).map((value: InnerValue<K, V>): V => value.value).values();
    }
    public clear(): void {
        this._innerMap.clear();
    }
}

type InnerHashKey = any;
type InnerValue<K, V> = {key: K, value: V};
class InnerMap<K, V> extends Map<InnerHashKey, InnerValue<K, V>> {}
```